# Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, forms, linqpad

I have a piece of code that throws an exception and error after running for a second time. Here it is:

```
static Form Window = new Form();
static public void Configuration()
{ 
    Window.Height = 800;
    Window.Width = 800;
    Window.Text = "Homework";

    Window.Paint += Window_Paint;

    Window.Show();
}
```

This code is inside a class and it throws an exception at "Window.Show();" saying that it:

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form'.
```

Please suggest a way that I can fix this so that it doesn't happen again.

Comment: " a way to fix this so that it doesn't happen again": don't use static `Form` object. create a new instance when necessary

Answer (score 0):

The code you probably want to use is:

```
static public void Configuration()
{ 
    var window = new Form();

    window.Height = 800;
    window.Width = 800;
    window.Text = "Homework";

    window.Paint += Window_Paint;

    window.Show();
}
```

This will ensure that a new instance of `Form` is created every time that `Configuration` is called.